# How to set not available ( {--} ) value to registry value of network adapter

Tags: powershell

I am facing a problem on how to set "Not available" value to network adapter via powershell.
Could not find any information about setting the value to {--} or just not available.
Registry value is showing the following: {--} and display value is -- when the "Not available" option is selected via UI.
[Advanced Network Adapter Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZDar.png)

Tried multiple powershell commands but non of them seemed to work.
Examples:

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet 3" -RegistryKeyword "VLAN_ID" -DisplayValue $null

Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet 3" -RegistryKeyword "VLAN_ID" -DisplayValue ""

Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet 3" -RegistryKeyword "VLAN_ID" -DisplayValue "-1"

Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet 3" -RegistryKeyword "VLAN_ID" -DisplayValue null

Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet 3" -RegistryKeyword "VLAN_ID" -DisplayValue "--"
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for either `Reset-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty` or `Remove-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you, `Remove-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty` worked perfectly!

Comment: Alan: Unless @Mathias wants to post an answer with the solution himself, I suggest you do it - it'll help future readers.